# Automatic Increment of Build number while creating the Matlab Standalone applications

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I am creating a standalone application having Version and Build number stored in a MAT file. I want auto-increment of the build number every time i compiled the code to create the standalone application. It has to take the previous build number from MAT file and increment by 1 and save it again in same MAT file before compiling the code.

I have tried by using 'startup.m' file. But it is incrementing the build number every time i opened the standalone application. Do you have any idea regarding auto increment of the build number before compiling the application every time..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ismcc()](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/compiler/ismcc.html) function to test that your code in startup.m is called from the mcc, something along the lines

```
if ~(ismcc || isdeployed)
   load(...);
   do your increment;
   save(...);
end
```

Comment: Its worked, but startup.m is common to whole matlab. Is there any function that is can add this code without involvement of the startup.m.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The way we handle build numbers is to generate an *.m function file returning the build number. This is done before compiling it into an executable. Advantage: The build number is contained in the code and cannot be _lost_.